# Best way to build a frozen dependencies Python wheel package

Tags: python, python-poetry

I would like to know the best way to build a python package (using poetry) but with all its dependencies frozen. And yes, this is a good idea, hear me out.

Today I have to use "poetry export" and write a prod-requirements.txt that I can feed to 'pip' using its '-c' parameter, for instance. This ensure I will install the same package with the same version than the on my application has been built and validated against.

And I could not do it with pipx for instance.

But before anyone would (kindly) try to explain to me that I do not need this feature, let me say straight: I need it (and even if you do not know, you need it too). Everybody should need this "frozen wheel" for any important Python application.

I am not talking about a shareable Python library that will not be executed directly, but using on another application. That is perfectly fine to deliver to the world, on pypi for instance, libraries that declare its dependencies with ranges.

But who never had a crash because one of the libraries in its virtual environment has been updated, and the author did not follow semver (because I do not want or do not know) and introduce regression, feature deprecation or even bugs. This happens ALL the time, and for libraries, this is not a problem. Developers should know how to manage this problem and put version guardian in the pyproject.toml, and so on.

But for application, this is not acceptable to have something breaking because one external developers broke something not related to you. Or because two modules are declaring incompatible version ranges (this happens currently between sphinx and flake8, each one dependending on incompatible version of import-resource).

This happened many times that I go urgent (of course) support of some of our application because pip installing it started doing weird thing, in the best situation it crashed at install, but sometime it got sneeky like only crashing on a specific routine. And even with "^1.2.3" version declaration it sometimes happens (even if this is suppose to means that the lib won't break anything upon updates). it happens and it always at the worst moment.

Of course I use docker images, but not all use cases relies on docker

My solution is to rely on pipx to let each application has their own virtual environment, and it works great. I am not at the level to basically empty the dev-dependencies of my project, but I would hope to have something similar, to be able to have each one of my dev-deps being automatically installed in its own virtualenv, so that sphinx do not mess with flake8 for instance.

But on my smaller scale, I am looking for producing wheel files for my applications with each dependencies frozen (some large application such as home assistant already does it, you cannot easilly install "free" version of each library in the environment it "controls").

My proposal for poetry has been rejected, which I regret because I do not had time and patience to explain why it is important to have this feature. So I am looking for a way to do it myself, in a composable way (so other can follow this principle or not).

Ideally I would like to have a tool that takes a wheel file, a frozen requirements.txt and produce a wheel with this requirements.txt embedded in it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve here. Sounds like you want separate venvs for each of your development tools (on a per project basis?), so that you can install the dependencies for your tests,  sphinx and flake8 exactly at the versions they and their dependencies require. If that is the case, then tools like [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) exist for that purpose. You tell it how to create a set of virtual environments and what commands to run in each of them.

Comment: I want my application to have a fully reproducible virtualenv when installed, for example with pipx.

Comment: Might be that we will implement something like this in the future. Please follow  https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2778

Comment: What's wrong with `pip freeze > requirements-frozen.txt`? It'll give the full versions of everything you have installed in the given virtual env. You can then give that to another virtual env and do `pip install -r requirements-frozen.txt`. You'll have a fully reproducible virtual environment (assuming nothing has been yanked).

Comment: I generate the frozen requirements.txt already. But the wheel is not « autonomous ». And it does not work with « pipx »